# Apply Odds Ratio Formula to Multiple Variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset (see below) with over a 1,000 records. For the purposes of the odds ratio calculations, the Covid_pos is the "dependent variable". All other variables are "independent variables" aka symptom variables. I have 15 additional symptom variables in addition to asymptomatic, fever, and cough variables. Here are all of symptom variables:

```
Symptoms =['Cough',"Nasal_Congestion","Wheezing_Asthma","Abdominal_Pain","Diarrhea","Vomiting","Rash","Fever","MED_ALERT_CPR_SHOCK_SEPSIS","Lymph_Node_Neck","Ear","Mouth Sores","Eye","SOB_WOB_Hyp_Desat","PNA","Nausea","Weak_Fatigue","Bodyaches","Dizziness","Fussy","Poor_PO_Dehydration","Tachycardia","COVID Exposure","COVID Test","COVID PUI" ,"COVID MIS","COVID Kawasaki","CP","ST","HA","Loss_Taste_Smell"]

ID   Covid_pos  Asymptomatic  Fever  Cough ...
0          1             0      1      0
1          0             0      0      1
2          1             1      0      1
3          1             0      1      0
4          0             1      1      0
5          1             0      1      0
6          0             1      1      0
7          1             0      0      1
8          0             0      0      0
9          0             0      0      0
```

I would like to conduct an unadjusted odds ratio for each symptom variable with the `COVID_POS` variable. To conduct the OR, I have the following code:

```
NCOdds=pd.crosstab(LABS_TAT.Nasal_Congestion,LABS_TAT.Covid_pos)
NCO = sm.stats.Table2x2(NCOdds)
print(NCO .summary())
```

[image]

Instead of copying and pasting and editing this code 15+ times, while changing the symptom variable, I wanted to know if it's possible to apply a for loop. Secondary, and perhaps better suited for separate question, I want the output to look like this:

[image]

Comment: yes you can run a `for loop for symptom in Symptoms`: ..`LABS_TAT[symptom]`..

Comment: thanks, what would be the full code for the for loop?